# Why doesn't my implementation of calling ASPNET Core 2.1 Database Migrate actually apply migrations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use a dedicated .Net Core 2.1 library to handle EF Core migrations. It all works well with the cli. I now want my ASPNET Core 2.1 WebApi to automatically migrate at startup. My WebApi references my Migration library.

Here is the interface and its implementation that I declare in my Migration library.

```
public class Migrator : IMigrator
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

    public Migrator(DbContextOptions options) => _options = options;

    public void Migrate()
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext(_options))
            context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}

public interface IMigrator
{
    void Migrate();
}
```

Here is my WebApi `Program.cs` (inspired from that [repo](https://github.com/KevinDockx/BuildingAsyncAPIAspNetCore/blob/master/Finished%20sample/Books/Books.Api/Program.cs))

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            try
            {
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating the database.");
            }
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

And here in my `startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<IMigrator, Migrator>(_ => new Migrator(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Write"))
            .Options));
```

It all builds and run an no exceptions are caught. However, my latest migration is not applied to the database.

UPDATE:

The accepted aswer led me to:

```
services.AddScoped<IMigrator, Migrator>(_ => new Migrator(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Write")));
```

and

```
public class Migrator : IMigrator
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Migrator(string connectionString) => _connectionString = connectionString;

    public void Migrate()
    {
        using (var context = GetContext(_connectionString))
            context.Database.Migrate();
    }

    private static MyContext GetContext(string connectionString)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GtaXContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.Context.Migrations"));
        return new MyContext (builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which assembly contains the `MyContext` class? And which assembly contains migrations?

Comment: There are 3 assemblies: one with `MyContext`, one with the migration scripts, one with the webapi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default EF Core migrator assumes that the assembly containing the migrations is the one which contains the target `DbContext` (`typeof(MyContext).Assembly`), which apparently doesn't apply in your case.

So you need to specify it explicitly via [MigrationsAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaldbcontextoptionsbuilder-2.migrationsassembly?view=efcore-2.1) method:

> Configures the assembly where migrations are maintained for this context.

For instance:

```
.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Write"), options => options
    .MigrationAssembly(typeof(Migrator).Assembly.FullName))
```

Comment: Indeed I had to do something similar with `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` and the cli. I knew it was related. Tks. However I endedup doing slightly differently that what you suggested: I'll update my post.